# Comparing two files in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file

I have a function that compares two files to see if they are the same. It reads the files byte by byte and checks to see they are the same.
The problem I'm having now is that for big files this function takes quite a long time.

What is the better, faster way to check if files are the same?

Comment: @Yavar -- comparing the files requires a read of all data along with a single instruction comparison. Hashing the data requires a read of all data along with more complex math. What am I missing that suggests the hash method will be faster (unless you're assuming the hash is pre-existing)? I must be missing something, since several posters suggest using a hash. I believe that unless the hash pre-exists, this is slower than memcmp.

Comment: Absolutely @mah +1 for your comment.

Comment: Hashing is a good solution when checking if a file downloaded over a network was not corrupted in transit. You generate a hash on the server and compare it with the hash of the downloaded file on the client side. It makes good sense in the context of file transfer over a network. It makes no sense when comparing two files sitting pretty on a disk.

Comment: Hashinh makes a lot of sense if you have 3+ files and you're looking for pairs of identical files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your files are not the same, are they likely to be of the same size? If not, you can determine the file sizes right away (fseek to the end, ftell to determine the position), and if they're different then you know they're not the same without comparing the data. If the size is the same, remember to fseek back to the beginning.

If you read your files into large buffers of memory and compare each buffer using memcmp() you will improve performance. You don't have to read the entire file at once, just set a large buffer size and read blocks of that size from each file, for each comparison iteration through your loop. The memcpy function will operate on 32 bit values, rather than 8 bit bytes.

Comment: I recommend this answer. When comparing two hashes, you can only have a high probability that the files are the same. You still cannot be 100% certain. Also, since you still need to read in data from both files in order to generate the hashes... you might as well just compare each block you read instead of calculating the hashes.

Comment: If both files are thrown away afterward and a hash isn't reused then a straight comparison might be best.  However, hashes are used because they are optimized at the CPU and toolkit level plus storing the hash for re-use saves a lot of processing later.

Comment: @PhilHannent: As mah already mentions, `memcmp` is also optimized at CPU level (in fact, some implementations will even use the CPU's SSE unit and operate on 64+ bits).

Comment: Solution is optimal, but using fseek/ftell causes me to lose sense. Why, on Windows (not on Earth!), you can't use `GetFileSize` instead?

Comment: @Ajay - you can use GetFileSize if that gives you the same info. Personally, I don't develop only for Windows and I need my code to build regardless of what system I'm on. I could write for Windows and use compatibility libraries, or I can just choose the method that works everywhere.

Comment: Since OP tagged 'windows', I suggested to use Windows API. `ftell` would anyway call `GetFileSize` internally (on Windows). I appreciate your compatibility concern!

Comment: Cheers. when using memcpy i have to get the info from the file to a char []. Is ReadFile the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm curious; let's say I open the files with fopen and iterate each with fgetc() and use that to compare.  I know this is a "non optimal" way to do this; but since we're dealing with buffered IO would there be a huge disadvantage?

Comment: @seand - yes. Ignoring the single byte read `fgetc()` does for a moment, you're still comparing only one byte at a time; your CPU is capable of comparing at least four bytes in the same instruction, so that adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. Beyond that, calling single byte (or even just small buffer) reads instead of one or few large buffer reads means you must call into a library much more frequently than necessary, adding significant additional overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want brute force comparison of two files, [mmaping may help](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/read_mmap.html).

If you know the file structure of what you are reading, read unique sections which allow you to identify them quickly (e.g. a header and relevant chunks/sections). Of course, you will want to get its basic attributes before comparing.

Generate hashes (or something) if you do multiple comparisons.

Comment: Your answer should be reversed. mmapping is a good suggestion, hashing is not. Searching file headers is a good solution, but only where applicable.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi but I qualified the applicability of hashing: "Generate hashes (or something) **if you do multiple comparisons**."

Comment: My apologies. Also, mmapping can be used to speed up the hashing process, with some very, very important caveats regarding pagefaulting.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi no problem. reversed, and added link.

Answer (score 0):

Read the files in chunks of size X. With X up to 1-10-50 megabytes. Use `memcmp()` on those chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst there are a number of examples of cryptographic hash functions using SHA or MD5, for file comparisons its better to use a non-cryptographic hash as it will be faster:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions

The FNV hash is considered fast for your needs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler_Noll_Vo_hash

Comment: Actually, for file comparison *no hash* is faster. Hashing requires read + calculation. Comparing requires just a read. Guess what's faster?

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Granted however its rare that you'd just do a straight compare, its more often the case that you can store the hash for a comparison again later.  Making just a hash of one file to compare when new data arrives.

Comment: Agreed.. The OP really needs to be more specific. It just currently reads like he's making a very näive binary (yes/no) diff program.

Answer (score -2):

If you are not familiar with hashing search on google about "MD5" or "SHA" algorithms.
Hashing is one of the efficient approaches to check consistence of files.
Only you need is to find implementation of one of this algorithms and check them; for example:

```
if(md5(file1Path) == md5(file2Path))
    cout<<"Files are equal"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"Files are not equal"<<endl;
```

Comment: Of course hashing is more efficient if you already have the hash completed in advance... but if you must compute the hash at run time, do you really believe you can generate a hash over x bytes faster than you can compare x bytes to x other bytes?